# <JAVASCRIPT/JSP> How to use ELSE IF in using radio box

Tags: javascript, jsp, if-statement

I have a radio box.

```
<td>
    <label for="requireDate"><input type="radio" id="date" value="requireDate" name="date" checked="checked"/>START DATE</label>
    <label for="finishDate"><input type="radio" id="date" value="finishDate" name="date" />END DATE</label>
</td>
```

Based on this value, two different Ajax function will be called when clicked on **SEARCH** button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#search').click(function() {         

if($('#date').val() == 'requireDate'){
    CommonUtil.ajaxPagingSubmit('<c:url value="${innovativepot}/A/SubscDtm" />', 1, $('#frm').serialize(), 'content');      
} else if ($('#date').val() == 'finishDate') {
    CommonUtil.ajaxPagingSubmit('<c:url value="${innovativepot}/A/cpltSubscDt" />', 1, ('#frm').serialize(), 'content');                
    }           
});
</script>
```

But for some reason, it calls up the first function for either one. 
Can someone tell me where is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both have the same id. Select by name.

Change to:

```
if($(':radio[name=date]:checked').val() == 'requireDate'){ ...
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have given the same `id` for `requireDate` and `finishDate`. `id` should always be unique.

Use a class selector to get what you want:

```
<input type="radio" id="date" value="requireDate" name="date" checked="checked" class='date'/>
<input type="radio" id="date" value="finishDate" name="date1" class='date'/>
```

**JS:**

`if($('.date').val() == 'requireDate')`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Use `$("input:radio[name=date]:checked").val()`

```
    $('#search').click(function() {   
        var dateVal = $("input:radio[name=date]:checked").val();
        if(dateVal == 'requireDate'){
            CommonUtil.ajaxPagingSubmit('<c:url value="${innovativepot}/A/SubscDtm" />', 1, $('#frm').serialize(), 'content');      
        } else if (dateVal == 'finishDate') {
            CommonUtil.ajaxPagingSubmit('<c:url value="${innovativepot}/A/cpltSubscDt" />', 1, ('#frm').serialize(), 'content');                
        }           
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need not use the same `id` for both the radio buttons.
Secondly, to access the `checked` radio button with `name="date"` try **`$("input[name=date]:checked").val()`**:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/86tXw/1/)

**Script:**

```
$('#search').click(function () {

    if ($("input[name=date]:checked").val() == 'requireDate') {
        // DO SOMETHING  
        console.log("start date");
    } else if ($("input[name=date]:checked").val() == 'finishDate') {
        //    DO SOMETHING ELSE           
        console.log("end date");
    }
});
```